# Migrate magento 1.9.3 to prestashop 1.16.1.18

Tags: magento, migration, prestashop, magento-1.9, prestashop-1.6

Actually I have 2 magento and I want to migrate both to one prestashop with multistore functionality.

I want migrate orders,products, and client. I show tutorials to migrate 1 magento to 1 prestashop. But I do not find nothing about migrate 2 magento to 1 prestashop multistore.

Some one can help to konow where start ?

Thank you

Comment: check this website that are paid one but there will be no headache to understand anything.  https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/

Comment: In my experience, you can choose Next-Cart or Cart2Cart. But I think Next-Cart can do it better because they customize the migration tool for each particular customer before processing the migration.

Answer (score 0):

In Prestashop there is an option to import data from a CSV file. And they offer templates you can download in back office. This could be a good starting point.
Analyse thouse templates and figure out how you can fill them with data from your Magento site. 
Generaly I would start by an analysis of SQL data structure of this two CMS and find out that field can go where from one to other. When I would write scripts that do the data migration. But first you have to understand well how data are organized and keept internaly in both.